# "Unable to infer type of a closure parameter 'b' in the current context". Getting this error while calling the function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swift3

getting error while calling the function.

```
func hitService<T : Codable>(urlS: String , completion : @escaping (T) -> Void) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlS) else {return}
    
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    let _ = session.dataTask(with: url) { dt, resp, err in
        
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        if let d = dt {
            
            do {
                let obj = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: d)
                completion(obj)
            } catch {print(error.localizedDescription)}
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

calling function like this and getting error on it.
I've tried passing a data type inside <> as well.

```
 hitService(urlS: urlStr) { b in
        
        
        
  }
```

Comment: Please update your question to show how you're calling the function

Comment: hitService(urlS: urlStr) { b in
            
            
            
        }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generic function relies on you specifying a type when it's called so it can infer the types it uses.

In this case you'll need to supply the type of the closure parameter `b` i.e.

```
hitService(urlS: urlStr) { (b: MyType) in
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.
also i noticed if i write something inside while calling function like print(b as String), then the error goes away.